# Javascript keep div toggled on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to keep a div toggled on a login/register form when the form is submitted or when the page is refreshed.

**How do I use cookie.js to remember the div that was toggled and keep it toggled when the form is submitted or when the page is refreshed?**

```
<a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');">Login</a>
<a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');">Register</a>  

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" style="display: block">
  default image
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="display: none"> 
 login box
</div>

<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3" style="display: none"> 
register box
</div>
```

And

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
$('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
         $(this).show(200);
    }
    else {
         $(this).hide(600);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I am trying to implement them at this moment. I will comment further soon. I am a noob so please forgive me and give me some time. Thank you.

Comment: Realistically, you probably need to ask a specific question.  At the moment your 'question' is a bit too general.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`I updated the answer.`

[**live demo with cookies enabled**](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/USXuT/)

[**live demo with cookies disabled**](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/USXuT/)

```
on load, you see the default picture.
on button1 click, you see the login.
on button2 click, you see the register.
and it appears the same way when you refresh the page (cookie setup)
```

Comment: That javascript toggle isn't working right, I want the div with class="newboxes" id="newboxes1" to display by default, then when the Login link is clicked, display the div with class="newboxes" id="newboxes2", then when the Register link is clicked, display the div with class="newboxes" id="newboxes3", and have it appear the same when the page is refreshed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes if it does what I want I will choose your answer

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: After more testing, the javascript doesn't work with my site for some reason. Thanks for you efforts, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cookie plugin like [this one](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), then

```
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes').not('#' + thechosenone).hide(600);
    $('#' + thechosenone).show(600);
    $.cookie('thechosenone', thechosenone);
}

jQuery(function($){
    var thechosenone = $.cookie('thechosenone');
    if(thechosenone){
        showonlyone(thechosenone)
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/USXuT/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That seems like it will work for me. I am running wordpress and wondering where to put the cookie plugin. Would it go in public_html/wp-includes/js/jquery?

Comment: @user2680557 sorry, not a wordpress guy

Comment: Is there a way to do this using just jquery and javascript and cookie.js without implementing a plugin?

Comment: what is cookie.js? is it a wordpress utility

Comment: @user2680557 if it can be used to set and get cookie value then you can replace the plugin with it