# How to keep selected/active HTML link color on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, page-refresh

**EDIT**:

I want to **keep selected keep HTML link color on page refresh**. I tried other problems that already been answered but didn't work on me.

*For example:*

When I clicked HTML link Categories the HTML link *Quizzes* it will change the color to red, and keep the color on page refresh.

**HTML**

```
<div id="col-navigation">
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <a href="#"> Quizzes </a>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#"> Categories </a>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#"> Jump </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div id="quizzes"> 
     Quizzes! <!-- default showed -->
</div>

<div id="categories" style="display:none">
     Categories! <!-- I have table here, plain text is just a example -->
</div>

 <div id="jump" style="display:none">
     Jump! <!-- I have table here, plain text is just a example -->
</div>
```

**JS/JQUERY:**

```
//SHOW AND HIDE
    $('#col-navigation a').click(function(){
   $('#quizzes,#categories,#jump').show().not('#' + $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase()).hide();
});

//STAY THE COLOR OF ACTIVE LINK
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().find('a').removeClass('focus');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('focus');
});
```

**CSS**

```
    li a {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.focus {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: red;
}

li a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Store "openness" in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`, then reconstruct on page load.

Comment: simpliest one would be for you to use `session`

Comment: @Amadan thanks i'll try it

Comment: Does this address the same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/18221121/1467396

Comment: @PhatWrat yes, I edited my question my first question was  solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the JS which should be triggered on DOM ready:

```
$('#col-navigation a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".content").hide().filter( $(this).data("target") ).show();
   localStorage.setItem('target', $(this).data("target"));
});
var target = localStorage.getItem('target');
!target || $('.content').hide().filter(target).show();
```

And here's the HTML; added `data-` attribute and `.content` class:

```
<div id="col-navigation">
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <a href="#" data-target="#quizzes"> Quizzes </a>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#" data-target="#categories"> Categories </a>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#" data-target="#jump"> Jump </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div id="quizzes" class="content"> 
     Quizzes! <!-- default showed -->
</div>

<div id="categories" style="display:none" class="content">
     Categories!
</div>

 <div id="jump" style="display:none" class="content">
     Jump!
</div>
```

[**Demo Using `localStorage` to remember last selected option**](https://jsfiddle.net/newnyeog/)

**UPDATE**

As for manipulation of the `.focus` class, some additional JS will suffice. No need to save any additional info in `localStorage`.

```
$('#col-navigation a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).addClass('focus').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('focus'); //<<<--THIS
   $(".content").hide().filter( $(this).data("target") ).show();
   localStorage.setItem('target', $(this).data("target"));
});
var target = localStorage.getItem('target');
!target || $('.content').hide().filter(target).show();
!target || $('a[data-target="' + target + '"]').addClass('focus').parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('focus'); //<<<-- AND THIS
```

[**Updated Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/newnyeog/1/)

Comment: Just edited the question. I have other problem. I hope you could help.

Comment: I have a little problem, every refresh the <div id="quizzes" class="content"> </div> which is the default showed is shows a bit before showing the selected div. I'm using a href link for the table pagination. 

P.S: There's no problem on keeping the selected div showed

Comment: That's because that's the current default behavior. You can change that to: hide everything until the page loads.

Comment: I need to have a default behavior to display.  Thank you sir.